# $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^3 e^{-x^8 \sin^2 x} dx$ and $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1} {1+ x^2 \sin^2 x} dx$ are not Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

This question is from Tom Apostol Mathematical Analysis.

> Prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^3 e^{-x^8 \sin^2 x} dx$ and $\int_1^{\infty}  \frac{1} {1+ x^2 \sin^2 x} dx$ are not Lebesgue integrable.

The problem is that I proved that both of them are Lebesgue integrable by using theorem 10.33

For (1) : Consider $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^3 e^{-x^8 \sin^2 x} dx\leq\int_{0}^{b} x^3 dx$ and the integral on the right is less than M for some M >0 and that M depends upon b.( I used property of $e^{-x}$ over when $x\in [0,\infty]$).

Similarly for (2):  $\int_1^{\infty}  \frac{1} {1+ x^2 \sin^2 x}dx \leq \int_{1}^{b} 1$= b-1=M .

So, what I am doing wrong and what is the right way of proving it?

Do you mind giving your time to this question?

Comment: What is $b$?$\,\,$

Answer (score 1):

Apostol's definition is as follows:
$f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $I$ if it can be written as $f= u-v$ where $u \in U(I)$ and $v \in V(I)$. The set $U(I)$ is the set of "upper functions" which he defines to be the functions $u$ which are limits of increasing sequences of step functions $s_n$ defined on $I$  such that $s_n \nearrow u$ almost everywhere on $I$ and  $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_I s_n  < \infty.$ He defines $V(I)$ similarly. In particular, $\int_I f = \int_I u  - \int_I v := \lim s_n - \lim t_n < \infty.$ The latter condition is what you're missing; the integral must be finite.

Now the functions you use as upper bounds do not have a finite itnegral and thus are not Lebesgue integrable, which is what is wrong with your argument.

What you need to do is to prove the integral is infinite. To do so, it suffices to find an appropriate lower bound whose integral is infinite, then monotonicity insures that your function has infinite integral. You need to analyze the quantitative behavior of both functions, for example: the function $\frac{1}{1+x^2 \sin^2(x)}$ is close to $1$ for $ x$ close to $ \pi + n \pi.$ You would be done if you prove that the integral around these points is big enough to make the integral infinite.